# StackOverflow losing its luster?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Is StackOverflow losing its lust? I have been on SO for almost 5 years now.. and the decision to rigidly limit SO for Q/A programming question only has severely reduce its attractiveness. Even conceptual programming questions are not allowed, for that we have programmers.stackexchange

Lots of useful discussions are being closed on the basis of 'unsuitable for SO', regardless of how many votes the questions and answers received.

I believe stackoverflow, programmers, superuser, and serverfault should be merged into one, and a more democratic process of closing and voting should take place.

All I am saying is moderation is good, but more democratization please.. right now it is almost becoming dictatorial. Questions are being closed by higher ranking users because it does not fit the format, doesn't matter how useful it is.

Comment: "I believe stackoverflow, programmers, superuser, and serverfault should be merged into one" - chaos would ensue.

Comment: "more democratic process of closing and voting should take place." - The current process is already democratic. The problem is not enough people care about closing, and that people keep complaining about being downvoted.

Comment: 3k is already very low. You don't want random foreigners (1-rep users are not citisens. They are visitors. Very disruptive visitors) to dictate your state's policy, do you?

Comment: I still have my lust, myself. Oh, wait...

Comment: Let me reword my argument. Maybe it is more productive if we just group these stackoverflow,programmer, and serverfault together we will have much greater pool of talents. I don't think there will be chaos, these 3 domains are interrelated anyway.

Comment: There is no wast of talents. If you think you are an expert on general computer usage you sign up at [su]. If not, you don't.

Comment: Trust me, the word you want is "luster", not "lust". And no, Stack Exchange hasn't jumped the shark yet.

Comment: Gotta disagree with the close votes here. This is much better suited to Meta.SE than any of the site specific meta sites. Just because the OP has misguided ideas about the network doesn't make the question off topic.

Comment: Forking of conceptually distinguished websites isn't bad. Programmers, SO, SF, etc. might have resemblance, but if they're separated, it's on good basis, because a lot of people voted for that, and that's democracy.

Comment: In my opinion many experts on SO are clinically rude. An elitist culture of know it alls that pray on questions that do not meet their own expectations. If SO continues with this mindset they will not last.

Answer (score 13):

The 3K limit doesn't imply it are very high ranked users. There are almost 24.000 users who can vote to close.

It takes 5 of them to close a question and 5 more to reopen it. If you can't find 5 people who vote to reopen in 24.000 users, probably the question wasn't too popular to keep open.

This is the most democratic way the system could work. The number of questions closed by moderators is very low compared to the total number of question.

Comment: Yes but there are lots of useful questions being closed because it belongs to superuser,programmers,serverfault, bla bla which I believe is counter productive.

Comment: They will be migrated instead of closed. They will be closed only when they are that much off-topic that migration gets rejected.